# Is there a more secure way than serialize()?

Tags: jquery, forms

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="loginForm"> 
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
    <br />
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" onkeypress="onEnterLogin(event);" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="loginButton" onclick="updateLogin();" value="Login">
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
function updateLogin() {
    $.post("login.php", 
        $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        function(html) {
            $("#north").html(html);        
        }
    );
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

```
$("#loginForm").serialize(),
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? `$.serialize` does precisely what you need. If you want something secure, use `https://`

Comment: Um, why do you think `serialize()` not secure?

Comment: `$.serialize` uses the same encoding as normal form submission. What more do you think you need?

Comment: use HTTPS if you want security.

Comment: So how do you make it so it uses HTTPS?

Comment: Is there a bluer colour than blue?

Comment: @xdazz: You can still see what the user submitted.

Comment: @Barmar: I understand that. How can it be more secure?

Comment: @Shomz: Do I need more than blue?

Answer (score 1):

To use HTTPS, put it in the URL of the script:

```
$.post("https://yoursite.yourdomain.com/path/to/login.php",
        $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            function(html) {
                $("#north").html(html);        
            }
    );
}
```

Of course, this also requires that you have an SSL server. Your hosting provider should probably be able to help you set that up.

Comment: There's rather more to setting up `https` than just putting it in your script: dedicated IP address, proper certificate from a trusted sources, configuration of the web server, usw. All of which are off topic for SO

Comment: Thank you for providing a helpful answer that I can look into deeper, it's insufficient so I can't mark it as the answer, but I'll give you an upthumb.